# O-minimal Theories with Non-Dense Order Type

Tags: logic, model-theory

In this [paper](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1986-295-02/S0002-9947-1986-0833698-1/S0002-9947-1986-0833698-1.pdf), Knight, Pillay, and Steinhorn prove that for any O-minimal structure $\mathfrak{A}$, in which the underlying order types is **dense**, and if $\mathfrak{B} \equiv \mathfrak{A}$, then $\mathfrak{B}$ is also O-minimal. Is there a counterexample for when the underlying order type is not dense? I haven't been able to construct one.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pillay and Steinhorn extended the result to o-minimal structures of arbitrary order-type in the [third paper in the series](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1988-309-02/S0002-9947-1988-0943306-9/S0002-9947-1988-0943306-9.pdf).

Comment: Thank you, I guess I just haven't gotten to it yet.

Comment: By the way, I just noticed this question was answered on Math Overflow a few hours before I answered it here. You're really supposed to wait more than 9 hours before cross-posting... see [here](http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1924/encouraging-patience-on-cross-posts)

Comment: My apologies, I was not aware of the etiquette. Thanks.